# Meteor.http.params sybmol screening

Tags: rest, meteor

Plus symbol converts to %2B and my request go wrong URL.
How fix it?
Code below.

```
// Result params:
// ?game=Dota%2B2&limit=1
// Error in game. Plus converts to %2B
// How Fix?

Meteor.call("getStreams", "Dota+2", "1", function(e, i) {

});

Meteor.methods({
    getStreams: function(game, limit) {
        var response = Meteor.http.call("GET",
            "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams",
            {params: {'game': game, 'limit': limit}});

        return response.data.streams.map(function(i) {
            return {
                "game" : i.game,
                "viewers" : i.viewers,
                "title": i.channel.display_name
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Request URL that i need: https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams?game=Dota+2&limit=1

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a hack, but you can just assemble the GET URI yourself:

```
    var response = Meteor.http.call("GET",
        "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams?game=" + game + "&limit=" + limit);
```

Be warned, though, that the variables aren't getting URI encoded anymore; this allows the `+` to pass through, but it could allow invalid characters to slip through as well. Be careful to validate `game` and `limit` before this call if they can ever be set by user input.